# Unable to Use IPv6 Tools from Command Line (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: macos, networking, ipv6

`ssh`, `ping6`, `traceroute6`, etc. all hang when I'm trying to access a host via IPv6.

My machine is configured for IPv6 as far as I can tell (via sites like http://ipv6-test.com, etc.)

I'm not sure where to start, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you trying numeric IPv6 address, or names? If names, maybe you're hanging when trying to look up AAAA DNS records (hostname -> IPv6 address mappings). Try pinging a known good IPv6 address.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I tried google's ipv6 address (2001:4860:4860::8888) with traceroute6 and that hung up too for some reason. However, it works with ping6. That's good enough for my purposes right now. Thank you.